# How to know if the user change the order of tabs of a AuiNotebook in wxPyhton?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I use a **AuiNotebook** in *wxPyhton* to handle information on different tabs. The user can fill information in the tabs, change the order of them thanks to drag and drop and then generate a sentence that summerize the informations in the tabs. The problem is that this sentence has to be regenerate when the user change the order of the tabs as the information in the tabs is order dependent (the meaning change when the order change).

So, I must know when the user change the order of the tabs to regenerate the sentence.

I already try to catch the *EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_END_DRAG* and the *EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_DRAG_DONE* events but they are called only when the user splits the tabs. They are not useful in my case.

Here is my code to try to do this:

```
from wx.aui import AuiNotebook, EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSED
from wx.lib.dialogs import ScrolledMessageDialog
from event import event_handler
import wx
import shlex, subprocess


class CommandNoteBook(Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, cmd, template_file, interface_file):
        super(Panel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.command = cmd
        self.notebook = AuiNotebook(self)
        #Refresh when info inside tab changes
        self.Bind(event_handler.EVT_VALUE_CHANGED, self.OnRefresh, id=wx.ID_ANY)
        #Refresh when a tab is closed
        self.Bind(EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSED, self.OnRefresh, self.notebook)
        #Refresh when tabs order change
        self.Bind(EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_END_DRAG, self.OnRefresh, self.notebook)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `bind` to the `wx.aui.EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_END_DRAG` event and set a variable there.

```
import wx
import wx.aui

class Frame1 (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__ (self,parent,id=wx.ID_ANY,title="Aui Notebook",size=(500,300))

        self.tabs_altered = False

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_auinotebook1 = wx.aui.AuiNotebook( self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.m_panel2 = wx.Panel( self.m_auinotebook1, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.p2_text = wx.StaticText(self.m_panel2, -1, "1 has not been moved", pos=(10,10))
        self.m_auinotebook1.AddPage( self.m_panel2, u"page1", True, wx.NullBitmap )
        self.m_panel3 = wx.Panel( self.m_auinotebook1, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.p3_text = wx.StaticText(self.m_panel3, -1, "2 has not been moved", pos=(10,10))
        self.m_auinotebook1.AddPage( self.m_panel3, u"page2", False, wx.NullBitmap )
        self.m_panel4 = wx.Panel( self.m_auinotebook1, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.p4_text = wx.StaticText(self.m_panel4, -1, "3 has not been moved", pos=(10,10))
        self.m_auinotebook1.AddPage( self.m_panel4, u"page3", False, wx.NullBitmap )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_auinotebook1, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )
        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Event
        self.m_auinotebook1.Bind(wx.aui.EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_END_DRAG, self.OnAuiDragend)

    def OnAuiDragend(self,event):
        page_idx = event.GetSelection()
        text = self.m_auinotebook1.GetPageText(page_idx)
        if text == "page1":
            self.p2_text.SetLabel("1 Moved")
        if text == "page2":
            self.p3_text.SetLabel("2 Moved")
        if text == "page3":
            self.p4_text.SetLabel("3 Moved")
        self.tabs_altered = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame1(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]